# how do you hide code in webpack but not node.js

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

i'm trying to write a library that works in both node.js and the browser. this code uses `window.fetch`, so i need a polyfill on the server. i would like to write my code something like this:

```
'use strict'

let fetch
if (ISNODE) {
  fetch = require('node-fetch')
} else {
  fetch = window.fetch
}

exports.get = params => {
  return window.fetch() // and so forth
}
```

in webpack, it should eliminate the `ISNODE` tree so that it doesn't try to `require('node-fetch')` at all.

how do you do this? for now, I'm making `window.fetch` a global.

Comment: Not sure but maybe taking a look at [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) could help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use webpack's Define plugin to define constants, then use the Uglify plugin (or something similar) to eliminate dead/unreachable code.

With the Define plugin, define a 'constant' variable for the environment in your build, like `IS_SERVER = true`. In your conditional, check that constant. Note that this only works when checking variables with boolean values, so it will understand `IS_SERVER = true`, but not `APP_ENV = 'server'`, for example.

Comment: awesome. is there a solution via babel plugin?

Comment: @JonathanOng I'm not using babel, so I'm not sure, sorry.